# GridView - How to bind a CodeProperty

Tags: wpf, listview, powershell, gridview

Here's a little program which will show the results of `Get-Childitem` in a WPF `GridView`. Columns for 'Name', 'Length', 'LastWriteTime', and 'Mode' are added.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework')

$grid_view = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Controls.GridView

$property_names = 'Name', 'Length', 'LastWriteTime', 'Mode'

foreach ($elt in $property_names)
{
    $grid_view.Columns.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn `
        -Property @{ 
            Header = $elt
            DisplayMemberBinding = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding -ArgumentList @(, $elt) 
        }))
}

$list_view = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Controls.ListView `
    -Property @{
        Name = 'abc'
        Margin = New-Object System.Windows.Thickness -ArgumentList @(, 10)
        View = $grid_view
    }

Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $list_view.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null }

$grid = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Grid

$grid.Children.Add($list_view) | Out-Null

$window = New-Object System.Windows.Window -Property @{ Content = $grid }

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Here's the resulting window:

[image]

Note that the 'Mode' column is empty.

What's so special about the 'Mode' property? Well, let's take a closer look at it:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\notepad.exe | Get-Member | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -match 'property' }


   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType     Definition                                                    
----              ----------     ----------                                                    
Mode              CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}                                 
PSChildName       NoteProperty   System.String PSChildName=notepad.exe                         
PSDrive           NoteProperty   System.Management.Automation.PSDriveInfo PSDrive=C            
PSIsContainer     NoteProperty   System.Boolean PSIsContainer=False                            
PSParentPath      NoteProperty   System.String PSParentPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSy...
PSPath            NoteProperty   System.String PSPath=Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::...
PSProvider        NoteProperty   System.Management.Automation.ProviderInfo PSProvider=Micros...
Attributes        Property       System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}                
CreationTime      Property       datetime CreationTime {get;set;}                              
CreationTimeUtc   Property       datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}                           
Directory         Property       System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}                      
DirectoryName     Property       string DirectoryName {get;}                                   
Exists            Property       bool Exists {get;}                                            
Extension         Property       string Extension {get;}                                       
FullName          Property       string FullName {get;}                                        
IsReadOnly        Property       bool IsReadOnly {get;set;}                                    
LastAccessTime    Property       datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}                            
LastAccessTimeUtc Property       datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}                         
LastWriteTime     Property       datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}                             
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property       datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}                          
Length            Property       long Length {get;}                                            
Name              Property       string Name {get;}                                            
BaseName          ScriptProperty System.Object BaseName {get=if ($this.Extension.Length -gt ...
VersionInfo       ScriptProperty System.Object VersionInfo {get=[System.Diagnostics.FileVers...
```

We can see that `Mode` is a `CodeProperty` whereas the properties that displayed properly are of `MemberType` `Property`.

If we change this line:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $list_view.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null }
```

to this line:

```
Get-ChildItem | select $property_names | ForEach-Object { $list_view.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null }
```

the `Mode` column values appear! :

[image]

What's going on here? Well, by running the output of `Get-ChildItem` through `Select-Object` and explicitly selecting properties, the MemberTypes are converted to type `NoteProperty`:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\notepad.exe | select Name, Mode | Get-Member


   TypeName: Selected.System.IO.FileInfo

Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
Mode        NoteProperty System.String Mode=-a---      
Name        NoteProperty System.String Name=notepad.exe
```

So apparently, `CodeProperty` properties don't seem to bind properly in this case.

Of course, I'd like to actually store the results of `Get-Chiditem` directly in the `ListView` as opposed the the `Selected` variants.

So my question is, is there a way to have a `CodeProperty` properly show up in the column?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `DataGrid` handles the `Mode` property just fine.

Here's a function called `Out-DataGrid` which uses `DataGrid` instead of `GridView` and `ListView`:

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework')

function Out-DataGrid ($properties)
{

```
$data_grid = New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid

$data_grid.IsReadOnly = $true
$data_grid.AutoGenerateColumns = $false

foreach ($elt in $properties)
{
    $data_grid.Columns.Add((New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn `
        -Property @{
            Header = $elt
            Binding = (New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding -ArgumentList @(, $elt))  
        }))
}

$data_grid.ItemsSource = @($input)

$grid = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Grid

$grid.Children.Add($data_grid) | Out-Null

$window = New-Object System.Windows.Window -Property @{ Content = $grid }

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

$data_grid.SelectedItem
```

}

Example use:

```
ls | Out-DataGrid -properties 'Name', 'Mode', 'Length'
```

[image]